# How to change the pen color of the chalkboard plugin of reveal.js in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, markdown, pandoc, reveal.js

I´m trying to change the pen color for the chalkboard plugin of reveal.js in RStudio. I have the following code:

```
---
title: "Presentation"
author: "Me"
date: "2018"
output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    theme: league
    transition: convex
    highlight: zenburn
    self_contained: false
    reveal_plugins: ["notes", "zoom", "chalkboard"]
    css: slides.css
    reveal_options:
      chalkboard:
        theme: whiteboard
        color: ['rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)'] # red
      previewLinks: true
      slideNumber: true
  beamer_presentation:
    toc: false
    incremental: false   
---
```

The color parameter should do the trick, but no matter what color I set I always get a black pen color if I set that parameter (default color is blue). How could I set It to any color I want?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If this is using the chalkboard plugin from Asvin Goel ([rajgoel](https://github.com/rajgoel)) then you need to set two colors in the configuration; one for the pen color and another for the chalkboard.

Try

```
color: ['rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)'] # red, red
```

See the configuration section in the readme: https://github.com/rajgoel/reveal.js-plugins/blob/master/chalkboard/README.md

Comment: This gives me an error, that's why I was using only one color (It changes the color to black with the actual code). I can change it in original reveal with yuor code but not in RStudio. Maybe a bug within the R implementation

Comment: I’m not familiar enough with the RStudio code. Might be worth submitting an issue to https://github.com/rstudio/revealjs/issues

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround:

Once you have knitted the file in rMarkdown, open up the HTML file in Notepad (or some other text editing document) and find the lines

```
chalkboard: {
      toggleNotesButton: true,
      theme: 'whiteboard',
 }
```

and add the color line manually

```
 chalkboard: {
      toggleNotesButton: true,
      theme: 'whiteboard',
      color: ['rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)'],
    },
```